# Why does my screen continuously dim during gaming, while plugged in

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1

i have an MSI gt70 with the nvidia GTX 675M. During game play, with the computer plugged in the screen with continuously go back and for between dim and bright. it is a smooth transition from bright to dim that happens every 2-3 seconds. when i unplug the computer it does not dim.
Why is it doing this and how do i stop it.
side note: just in case it matters, im not using the factory charger as it broke. i am using a rocketfish 90W adapter

Comment: Its possible the problem is with the adapter.  What are your power profile settings set to?

Comment: I wish it could be a hardware issue... a failing/bad screen.

Answer (score -1):

While gaming, the laptop consumes more power than when idle. Perhaps your replacement adapter is not able to maintain a constant high power supply, and therefore it keeps switching to battery power. 
I'm not sure why the screen goes dimmer. Maybe it's trying to save power.

I suggest that you search for an official replacement of the original charger for your laptop model, if possible, or at least one with good reviews. Using a low quality third-party charger that has not been approved could lead to permanent damages to your battery or motherboard.

A quick online search for your laptop model showed 180W charger. So maybe the 90W one you're using is not enough. Haven't you noticed a decrease in charging time since you've got it?

Comment: no i havent really noticed a difference in charging time. if anything i feel like it dies a little faster. but i have been reading a lot of articles about it switching to battery power and then back to charging, and that makes a lot of sense. ill probably go buy a new charger with the appropriate rating. Thanks for your input

Answer (score -1):

Power supply, power profile, possible virus/trojan (I've seen some absolutely hilarious virii), malfunctioning internals (backlight or inverter is possibly on the fritz)... Only way to know for certain where the problem is beginning is with monitoring gear. A lot of 'green' power boards actually give power readings nowadays which will help determine whether it is drawing a constant but varying amount of power periodically and regularly. That will determine whether it is power supply. Then it's a case of working backwards though I don't really like the idea of running a laptop with electronics open with multimeter monitoring it...